# Error al utilizar servicios y HttpClient con observables

Tags: typescript, angular5

Quiero utilizar servicios y `HttpClient` con observables, al usar `HttpClient` sin servicio todo funciona muy bien pero al pasarlo como servicio no he podido lograr utilizarlo.

Investigando leí que debo utilizar observables en el servicio para posteriormente en el componente subscribirme y traer la data. NO he logrado traer la respuesta al componente, es importante mencionar que no utilizo `http` sino `HttpClient` donde ya me llega como `Json` (para que no me den respuestas basadas en `http`).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";
import { video, videosgeneral } from '../models/videos';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class VideosService {
  videos: Array<video>;
  videoid: Array<video>;
  listavideos:Array<video>;
  public VideosApi = 'https://xxx.xxx.cl/api/v1/video';
  public token = 'xxxxxx';
  public paginas:number;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {  


  }

  getVideos(): Observable<any>{
    const headers = { 'Authorization': 'bearer xxxxxx' };
    const params = { 'page': '1' };  
    return this.http.get(this.VideosApi, { headers:headers, params });

  }



}
```

Componente ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpEventType  } from "@angular/common/http";
import { video } from '../models/videos';
import { VideosService } from '../servicios/videos.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers:[VideosService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public videosService:Array<any>;
  public listavideos:any;
  public videos: video[];

  constructor(private http : HttpClient, videoService: VideosService) {
    this.listavideos.getVideos().subscribe(
      data => {

          if(data.code != 200){
              console.log(data);
          }else{
            this.listavideos = data['videos']['data'];
            console.log(data['videos']['data']);
          }

      },
      error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
      }
  );


  }  


  ngOnInit() { 



  }


}
```

HTML componente:

```
<div class="row"> 
      <div class="col s12 m4 l3" *ngFor="let video of listavideos"  id="{{video.vid}}">
        <div class="video">
          <div class="thumb">
            <div class="hover-efect"></div>
            <small class="time">{{video.duration}}</small>
            <a routerLink="/video"><img [src]="video.thumb" alt=""></a>
          </div>

          <div class="video-info">
            <a routerLink="/" class="title truncate">{{video.name}}</a>
            <a class="channel-name" routerLink="/">Categoria: {{video.category}}<span>
                          <i style="display:none;" class="material-icons">person</i></span></a>
            <span class="views">
              <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>{{video.total_views}} visitas
            </span>
            <span class="date">
              <i class="material-icons">access_time</i>{{video.begins}}
            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**ERROR:**

> Error: [object Object]
>       Stack trace:
>       resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:821:31
>       resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:785:17
>       scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:870:17
>       ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17
>       onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4941:24
>       ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17
>       Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28
>       drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:594:25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu componente tiene varias cosas mal:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public videosService: Array<any>; //esta variable no se usa para nada
    public listavideos: any; //no se inicializa
    public videos: video[];


    constructor(private http: HttpClient, videoService: VideosService) {
        //listavideos es undefined, es videoService lo que estás buscando
        this.listavideos.getVideos().subscribe(
            data => {

                if (data.code != 200) {
                    console.log(data);
                } else {
                    this.listavideos = data['videos']['data'];
                    console.log(data['videos']['data']);
                }

            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //deberías hacer la petición aquí, no en el constructor
    }

}
```

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería algo como:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public listavideos: video[];


    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private videoService: VideosService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.videoService.getVideos().subscribe(
            data => {

                if (data.code != 200) {
                    console.log(data);
                } else {
                    this.listavideos = data['videos']['data'];
                    console.log(data['videos']['data']);
                }

            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: gracias! esto lo soluciono! debía definir como private el servicio, pensé qué con poner una coma lo tomaría pero al parecer tomaba por defecto public.

Comment: No te confundas, con `public` también funcionaría... es cuando no pones nada cuando no funciona. `public` o `private` lo que hacen es crear un atributo con el mismo nombre del parámetro dentro de la clase. En Javascript sería el equivalente a `constructor(dato) { this.dato=dato;}`

Comment: comprendo, muchas gracias!